# Swift Charts Setting LineMark on top of BarMarks

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

Is there any way to make a chart having LineMark connecting tops of the BarMarks, but for a certain period (for example, a week-7 days), with some days not having BarMarks at all (in that case, LineMark would have to go from for.example Tuesday directly to Friday BarMark top)

I've tried putting BarMarks and LineMark in the same Chart, no success.

I've tried setting BarMarks through the list, or separately.
The issue I was having is that LineMark needs to have same number of elements as the BarCharts - and it have to be 7 of them (for each day). Having that, LineMark will go to zero, or end prematurely.

Code:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Chart {      
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 0),
                y: .value("Sales", 10), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 1),
                y: .value("Sales", 200), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 2),
                y: .value("Sales", 0), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 3),
                y: .value("Sales", 0), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 4),
                y: .value("Sales", 0), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 5),
                y: .value("Sales", 120), width: 10)
        BarMark(x: .value("Day", 6),
                y: .value("Sales", 40), width: 10)

        ForEach(Array(numbers.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, value in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Index", index),
                y: .value("Value", value)
            )
        }
    }
}
```